# Entity Framework is there a way to see what is in cache?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is there a way of looking at whats already in cache? I just want to ensure that I'm not making repeated database calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, sure is, you can use:

```
context.<YourSet>.Local
```

to see all entities currently tracked by the context